# TYPO3 Important Notice message

Tags: typo3

I have TYPO3 8.7.1 installed and when I login to backend in "About modules" page a red message appears: "Important Notice!

One or more problems were detected with your TYPO3 installation. Please check the status report for more information."

How can I remove this? Because in Reports > Status report, only things that I'm not sure about are these, but they don't show as errors, just notices:

- updates   Update Incomplete
- Your system registers XCLASS

Comment: I recommend to use install tool and use the "Upgrade Wizard" to complete update.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If you want disable all systems related `Important Notice message`.

Then you can disable systems extension `reports`. I am not sure, but i think all system related important notice message are generated through this extension.

Comment: I think solving the reported errors is better than remove reporting.